# Перевести так, чтобы не надо было склонять имена участников

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

Конкурсные вопросы имеют такое описание:

> Это конкурсный вопрос с наградой размером +500 баллов репутации от Чад, срок окончания через 3 дня.

Как мне кажется, было бы правильнее так

> +500 баллов репутации от Чада

но подозреваю, что склонять имена участников довольно сложно. Поэтому, стоит ли перевести так, чтобы не надо было их склонять? Например:

> +500 баллов репутации от участника Чад

(ну если так можно, я плохо знаю русский язык, честно говоря)

Comment: Да, так вполне хорошо звучит. Делает текст немного более формальным, но зато избавляет от необходимости в склонении.

Comment: Но страдает гендерная нейтральность, т.к. участница — это не участник. Надо подумать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да? Женщина не может быть участником, только участницей? Тогда значит, что у нас много таких проблем, например «у этого участника пока нет сообщений».

Comment: ну, здесь достаточно тонкий момент. Участница `==` участник, но не `.equals`, как-то так )) То есть существуют парные термины, когда мужской род используется для лиц любого пола, женский — только для женского. По-хорошему тут бы менять движок, чтобы он подставлял строки, соответствующие полу, указанному в профиле.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я не вижу такая настройка в профиле. Кажется, нельзя менять по полу.

Comment: действительно, я тоже не увидел. Похоже, выбор строк по полу практически нереализуем.

Comment: Боюсь, если мы заставим выбирать между мужским и женским полом, обидятся какие-нибудь трансгендеры. В ФБ, кажется, можно выбирать между мужским, женским, или написать своё название.

Comment: @VladD: трансгендеры своих падежных окончаний пока не требуют?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Тсссс! Не дай бог услышат!

Comment: Я не знаю, что позволяет  движок, но может где-то в настройках просто спросить пользователя, как правильно склонять имя? И написать автосклонятор, который покроет 80% случаев автоматически.

Comment: вот это вот "500 баллов от участника Чад" - это кошмар.

Comment: @n0rd: сейчас в настройках и в движке такой функциональности нет, [и скорее всего не будет](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265436/2790048)

Comment: Ну это все-таки не вопрос гендерной идентификации, а вопрос правильного построения предложений. Хотя для глаголов и прилагательных нужен пол...

Comment: @NickVolynkin гендерная нейстальность не страдает, директор тоже может быть женщиною, такое и бывало и ныне и в сов.время

Comment: Похоже, решение принято. Не могли бы вы принять ответ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Может быть, так? Теперь ещё и для участников любого пола.

> Это конкурсный вопрос, за который Чад предлагает награду в +500 баллов репутации; срок окончания конкурса через 3 дня.

Comment: +1, но сможем ли мы так хитро славировать во всех остальных текстах?

Comment: @VladD: будем пробовать. Где сможем — славируем )

Comment: А еще, тут акцент не на награде, а на человеке, который ее предлагает.

Answer (score 3):

Универсальное слово – **пользователь**.

> Конкурсный вопрос от пользователя Чад/Алиса/Оно.
>
> Пользователь Чад/Алиса/Нечто предлагает в качестве награды за решение...

Кроме того, у слова *пользователь* нет гендерных склонений.

**UPD**
*Пользователь* – является гендерно-нейтральным понятием. Не словом, а именно понятием. Мы же не говорим "библиотекарша", "секретарша" или "операторша". Вернее, кто говорит – говорит неправильно.

Конечно же допустимо сказать "пользовательница", но только в том случае если нужно подчеркнуть гендерную принадлежность.

Пример:

Понятие *пользователь* сродни понятию *читатель*. То есть это лексическое **обобщение**. Например, автор может написать в лирическом отступлении: "*Вероятно, читатель уже заметил... и.т.д.*" или "*Внимание читателя привлёк персонаж Ленского...*".

Но никаких читательниц! ;) Ибо читательницы входят в состав читателей, так же как дамы входят в состав господ.

Comment: Пользовательница?

Comment: @n0rd да нет, нет конечно же )) никакой "пользовательницы". Только *пользователь*. Это гендерно-нейтральное понятие.

Comment: *Учитель-учительница* - можно, а *пользователь-пользовательница* - нельзя? Что-то тут не так.

Comment: @n0rd я апдейтнул ответ. Надеюсь, станет яснее. Ща напишу еще один апдейт.

Comment: Слово «пользовательница» в языке есть. Другое дело, что оно употребляется больше в неформальном общении и редко встречается в официальных документах. Дело в другом. Например, у слова «товарищ»  точно нет варианта женского рода. Вспомните, насколько уродливо звучит «товарищ Анна Иванова». Любой термин мужского рода, использованный с женским именем, обычно звучит именно так.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а я и не утверждал что такого слова нет. Я лишь указал на разницу между понятием и словом. И, кстати, я не согласен, что слово мужского рода всегда отвратительно звучит сущностью женского рода: секретарь красивая, учитель биологии Ольга Анатольевна, оператор Алла здорово мне помогла, и т.д.

Comment: Но *пользовательница* точно не катит. Слово есть, а использование его для целей ОП было бы большой ошибкой.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: «пользовательница» конечно не катит. Тем более, SE не различает нас по полу и не сможет предоставить соответствующие строки.

Comment: Но и замена «участников» на «пользователей» не дает существенного улучшения. Кроме того, предпочитаемый термин — это именно «участник»: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1054/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin Интересно, спасибо. Почитал и отписал туда свой взгляд на вещи.

Comment: `Вернее, кто говорит – говорит неправильно.` >> Какое правило об этом говорит?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ я затрудняюсь сходу привести правило, но такие слова как *режиссерша, операторша, библиотекарша и пр.* относятся явно к разговорным новообразованиям. Я не исключу, что по ним и нет регламента. Вон, например, Александр Розенбаум в одной из своих песен использует слово "акандемиком" (в знач. "академик"). Но это же неправильно, не так ли?

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown (о акандемике) да это пожалуй не правильно, однако это скорее проблема правописания, нежели грамматики, вот например вы говорите как: он находится в лесу , или: он находится в лесе?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ коллега, не сердитесь, но я не готов к лингвистическим диспутам. Хорошо бы остаться в рамках вопроса, вынесенного в заголовок. С надеждой на понимание.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: несколько странно видеть спор о лингвистике с человеком, который ставит пробел перед запятой. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin вот ты все-таки перфекционист )))

Comment: "Конкурсный вопрос от пользователя Чад/Алиса/Оно." А если вопрос задан одним пользователем, а награду предлагает другой, то от кого же этот конкурсный вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy если такое возможно, тогда это *Конкурсный вопрос от пользователя Чад с наградой от пользователя Алиса.*

Comment: @Qwertiy: в таком случае мой вариант подходит без изменений. ))

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, это не только возможно, но и даже значок дают за это :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да. Но я же не его комментировал ;)

Answer (score 3):

И у нас есть явный победитель! Исправил в транзифексе согласно тексту в верхнем ответе.